# After installing Tensorflow-gpu i got error Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime

Tags: tensorflow

I have installed redhat 6.6, cuda 9.0, cudnn 7.3.1 and tesnorflow-gpu. but after installation getting following error. My graphics card is nvidia titan v 
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-88d96843a926>", line 1, in <module>
    import keras

  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils

  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils

  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K

  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *

  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf

  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import

  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tested your installations of cuda and cudnn:

**Nvidia drivers:**

```
$ nvidia-smi
```

This should display you an overview of the metrics of your GPU

**Test cuda:**

Check first if:

```
$ nvcc -V
```

display the right version of your cuda toolkit

Then you can test it with the following process:
First:

```
 $ cd ~/NVIDIA_CUDA-9.0_Samples
 $ make
```

And then:

```
$ cd ~/NVIDIA_CUDA-10.0_Samples/bin/x86_64/linux/release
$./deviceQuery
```

if you have a 'Result: pass' at the end, you're all good!

**To test cudnn:**

```
$ cp -r /usr/src/cudnn_samples_v7/ $HOME
$ cd $HOME/cudnn_samples_v7/mnistCUDNN
$ make clean && make
$ ./mnistCUDNN
```

You should have as result: 'Test passed!'

**Tensorflow:**

If cuda and cudnn are working, i advice you to install tensorflow in a conda environment using:

```
conda create --name tf_gpu tensorflow-gpu
```

For me (and after a lot of problems) it was working very well.

To test it:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

**main sources:**
[install tensorflow GPU](https://medium.com/@cjanze/how-to-install-tensorflow-with-gpu-support-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-with-cuda-10-nvidia-gpu-312a693744b5)
[tensorflow for GPU made easy](https://towardsdatascience.com/tensorflow-gpu-installation-made-easy-use-conda-instead-of-pip-52e5249374bc)